Vite app build index.html shows a blank page
I am trying to deploy a Vite + Vue3 web app to a Flask server.
The Vite app is configured like this :
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'


import tailwind from "tailwindcss"
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer"


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwind(), autoprefixer()],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  base: "./",
  build: {
    assetsDir: "static",
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: (id) => {
          if (id.includes('/node_modules/vuedraggable')) {
            return 'vendor_vuedraggable';
          } else if (id.includes('/node_modules/mathjs')) {
            return 'vendor_mathjs';
          }else if (id.includes('/node_modules/@vue')) {
            return 'vendor_@vue';
          } else if (id.includes('/node_modules/')) {
            return 'vendor';
          } else {
            return 'index';
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

I already added the "base" key but the files are correctly sent :
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2024 11:23:13] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2024 11:23:13] "GET /static/index-CUxeN559.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2024 11:23:13] "GET /static/vendor_@vue-BPht8hiF.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2024 11:23:13] "GET /static/vendor-BHsEwUvg.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2024 11:23:13] "GET /static/vendor_vuedraggable-C4waPfg2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2024 11:23:13] "GET /static/vendor_mathjs-cBMnjtiC.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2024 11:23:13] "GET /static/index-DeKIcMaG.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -

The flask server gets the file thank to these lines.
@app.route('/')
def welcome():
  return serveFile('index.html')

@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def serveFile(filename):
  return send_from_directory("frontend/dist", filename)

@app.route('/static/<path:filename>')
def my_static(filename):
  return send_from_directory("frontend/dist/static", filename)

(Removing the chunking doesn't matter)
If I go to "localhost:5000/", the website is displayed correctly.
But the url "localhost:5000/index.html" displays a blank page even though serveFile is called in both situation.
Here is the html file :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/static/index-CUxeN559.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/static/vendor_@vue-BPht8hiF.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/static/vendor-BHsEwUvg.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/static/vendor_mathjs-cBMnjtiC.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/static/index-CUxeN559.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/static/vendor_vuedraggable-C4waPfg2.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/static/index-DeKIcMaG.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>

What do I have to do to make "localhost:5000/index.html" display my web app?

Does the app use a router? If it doesn't, I see no way how vite/vue could affect the way url is processed

If your app has a router it will search for a route /index.html. If this is not the case, check your console for errors.

You were both right, the router was the problem. As the router only links to one view, I think I'll see to remove it or simply add a /index.html route

@Broot A client-side router needs to be backed up by the server to make it work. You didn't explain your case and why you needed /index.html. For a way that will work with any server-side and base url, consider using hash router strategy

I'm using a specific medical server called Orthanc and that allows plugins.
Here is an example of the URL you can have : link.
In my different tests, I saw if that server renders the web app as static, it was easier for me to organize my API.
That's the reason why I need the URL to directly point to the html file.
If I currently only have a single view, but if needed I'll use the hash router strategy
